# How to select language in videos through the khan academy API?

Tags: khan-academy

I am incorporating the api of khan academy and I need to receive videos from the platform in Spanish, the incorporation is made in PHP, I need to know if there is any way to request the videos in a specific language, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would change the Khan Academy subdomain from `www` to `es` for accessing Spanish content.

Here's an example API URL for a Spanish statistics video:
https://es.khanacademy.org/api/v1/videos/statistics-intro-mean-median-and-mode

Hope this helps, kindly vote up and accept this answer if it does!